# move team from project to another project Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

azure devops move team from project to another project

is it possible ? because is already scoped to 100 library because to generate the same group on another project we will need to scope them again.

azure devops > teams > move team

Answer (score 0):

Currently, moving Team from one project to another is not supported in Azure DevOps Service.

As far as I know, there is no work around for your demand neither.

If you want this feature to be supported in Azure DevOps, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion